# How to map function over numpy with condition on each variable?

Tags: python, numpy

I get this error when trying to do map this function over the numpy array:

```py
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> g = lambda x: 0 if x % 2 == 0 else 1
>>> g(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I was expecting result `array([ 1,  0,  1, 0, 1])`

When it works fine in this case:

```py
>>> f = lambda x: x ** 2
>>> f(a)
array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25])
```

What can I do to map function g over the array `a` faster than a for loop, preferably using some of numpy's faster code?

Comment: As an aside, `lambda` creates an anonymous function. If all you do is assign it to a variable, thereby naming it, use a `def` instead. This works, but is of questionable style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has problems:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
g = lambda x: 0 if x % 2 == 0 else 1
g(a)
```

A lambda is essentially just an unnamed function, which you happen to be naming here, so you might as well:

```
def g(x):
    return 0 if x % 2 == 0 else 1
```

But that's still a bit odd, since taking an integer modulo 2 already is 0 or 1, so this would be the same (when applied to integers, which is what you're looking to do):

```
def g(x):
    return x % 2
```

At which point you have to wonder if a function is needed at all. And it isn't, this works:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a % 2
```

However, note that the mistake you made is that `f = lambda x: x ** 2` followed by `f(a)` works not because it applies the operation to each element - it applies the operation to the array, and the array supports spreading of the operation to its elements for raising to a power, just like it does for the modulo operator, which is why `a % 2` works.

Result:

```
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Note that this type of spreading isn't something that generally works - you shouldn't expect Python to just do the spreading when needed for any data type (like a list or set). It's a feature of `numpy`'s implementation of arrays, the operations have been defined on the array and implemented to spread the operation over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute mathematical some operations such as exponents on entire numpy arrays so you're doing the equivalent of `np.array([ 1,  2,  3, 4, 5])**2`. <strike>But you cannot use the modulus operator on a numpy array hence giving you an error.</strike>
The lambda function is being applied to the entire array here not each individual element.

You can use `np.vectorize` here instead:

```
modulus = np.vectorize(lambda x: 0 if x % 2 == 0 else 1)
modulus(a)
```

Comment: _"But you cannot use the modulus operator on a numpy array"_ isn't true. The issue is trying to evaluate the truthiness of an array, which numpy intentionally doesn't define to avoid mistakes like this. `x % 2 == 0` is okay, but `if (x % 2 == 0)` is not.

Comment: Although you *can* use vectorise here, it's in no way faster than using the built-in spreading of an operator like `%`, so it's not recommended (although it does work for operations that `numpy` doesn't support directly)

Answer (score 0):

Let's decompose this. The general form of your ternary expression is `x if C else y`, with `C` being the comparison. Let's pull out just that comparison to see what we get:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a % 2 == 0
array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

That mod and comparison gives a new array where each value as been moded and compared. Now you throw in an `if` (in this case `if array([False,  True, False,  True, False])`). But should this `if` be true if all of the array elements are `True` or maybe just a single one? What if the array is empty, is that different? That's why pandas has the methods listed in the error message - you have to decide what `True` is.

But not in this case. You really just wanted the base 2 modulus of each element and you don't have to work so hard to get it.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a % 2
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

There's your answer!

Comment: @Grismar - I added some text to help clear that up.